# Reticulate: Extract SKLearn Decision Path in R

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, decision-tree, reticulate

I am using reticulate with sklearn.ensemble and I would like to extract decision paths.

```
library(reticulate)

# set up data for sklearn
features = names(iris[1:4]) # extract explanatory variables
iris_mat = data.matrix(iris[ , features])
y = as.factor(iris$Species) # format response variable as factoy

# load sklearn
sk = import("sklearn.ensemble")
clf = sk$RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=10)
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=as.integer(10),
                         random_state=as.integer(0), 
                         n_estimators=as.integer(101)) 
# fit the model
clf.fit = clf$fit(X = iris_mat, y= as.double(y))
clf.decision = clf$decision_path(iris_mat)
```

My question is: how can i extract the sparse decision matrix that is saved with the clf.decision object? clf.decision is a list, with typeof(clf.decision[[1]]) being an "environment" that contains the matrix.

Thank you!

Comment: If it's an environment, try `ls(envir=clf.decision[[1]])` to get the names of the objects in that environment. Or `ls.str(envir=clf.decision[[1]])` to also see what types of objects are in there. You can extract an object from an environment with it's name using `$` like you do with named lists.